# Selecting rows from a Pandas dataframe with a compound (hierarchical) index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I'm suspicious that this is trivial, but I yet to discover the incantation that will let me select rows from a Pandas dataframe based on the values of a hierarchical key. So, for example, imagine we have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame({'group1': ['a','a','a','b','b','b'],
                       'group2': ['c','c','d','d','d','e'],
                       'value1': [1.1,2,3,4,5,6],
                       'value2': [7.1,8,9,10,11,12]
})
df = df.set_index(['group1', 'group2'])
```

df looks as we would expect:

[image]

If df were not indexed on group1 I could do the following:

```
df['group1' == 'a']
```

But that fails on this dataframe with an index. So maybe I should think of this like a Pandas series with a hierarchical index:

```
df['a','c']
```

Nope. That fails as well.

So how do I select out all the rows where:

1. group1 == 'a'
2. group1 == 'a' & group2 == 'c'
3. group2 == 'c'
4. group1 in ['a','b','c']

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Try using `xs` to be very precise:

```
In [5]: df.xs('a', level=0)
Out[5]: 
        value1  value2
group2                
c          1.1     7.1
c          2.0     8.0
d          3.0     9.0

In [6]: df.xs('c', level='group2')
Out[6]: 
        value1  value2
group1                
a          1.1     7.1
a          2.0     8.0
```

Comment: I *knew* there had to be a more simple idiom. Thanks!

Comment: what about `group1 in ['a','b','c']`

Comment: df[[group1 in ['a', 'b', 'c'] for group1, group2 in df.index]]

Comment: @lodagro that absolutely works, but I have no idea why. Can you explain how `[group1 in ['a', 'b', 'c'] for group1, group2 in df.index]` works?

Comment: df.index behaves like a tuple list here. So you iterate through the tuples, discarding group 2 (you assign the first element of each tuple to "group1" and the second to "group2" but only use "group1") and checking whether the first element of the tuple is in the list ['a', 'b', 'c']. This creates a boolean mask which is then used for the subsetting.

Comment: I suspect though that np.in1d(df.index.labels[0], [label_of_a,label_of_b,label_of_c]) will be much faster and does the same job. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: np.in1d(df.index.labels[0], match(['a','b', 'c'], df.index.levels[0])) seems to do the trick the way I understood the MultiIndex code (labels are created using Categorical.from_arrays(values) )

Comment: Technique used is boolean indexing (see also http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing). Arthur explained how i created the boolean index, as he indicated there are other ways to create the True/False iterable. But in the end it comes down to boolean indexing for part #4 of your question. Note that Arthur opened an issue on GitHub with a request to simplify this use case (see https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/1766).

Comment: Thank you all for both explaining things to me and also spending the time and energy to make Pandas better.

Answer (score 9):

Syntax like the following will work:

```
df.ix['a']
df.ix['a'].ix['c']
```

since `group1` and `group2` are indices. Please forgive my previous attempt!

To get at the second index only, I think you have to swap indices:

```
df.swaplevel(0,1).ix['c']
```

But I'm sure Wes will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: That won't work, because `'group1' == 'a'` is simply False, so this is just `df.ix[False]`, or `df.ix[0]`.  As a result, `df.ix['group1'=='a']` will be exactly the same as `df.ix['group2'=='d']`.

Comment: We're close... but something's not quite right. When I do `df.ix['group2'=='d']` I only get one record back... and it's the first record, not one where group2==d.

Comment: @JDLong: it's the first record because 'group2' == 'd' is False, which is 0.  Every one of these comparisons is evaluated *first*, and so it's `.ix[0]`, `.ix[0,0]`, and `.ix[0]` again.

Comment: so `df.ix['a'].ix['d']` works... so that covers the first two examples. But how would I select only on the second part of the index?

Comment: I like the swaplevel... but not sure how to use it for indexes with more than 2 levels. Naturally my real life application uses a deep index :(

Comment: Well, as long as you knew the depth of the index, you can always `swaplevel(0,x)`, but I assume you do not necessarily know the index of the index!

Comment: swaplevel also takes names as parameter, so if you know at least the name of it, that could help.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 0.19.0 there is a new suggested approach, which is explained here[1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index). I believe the clearest example they give is the following, in which they slice from a four-level indexing. This is how the dataframe is made:

```
In [46]: def mklbl(prefix,n):
   ....:     return ["%s%s" % (prefix,i)  for i in range(n)]
   ....: 

In [47]: miindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([mklbl('A',4),
   ....:                                       mklbl('B',2),
   ....:                                       mklbl('C',4),
   ....:                                       mklbl('D',2)])
   ....: 

In [48]: micolumns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([('a','foo'),('a','bar'),
   ....:                                        ('b','foo'),('b','bah')],
   ....:                                       names=['lvl0', 'lvl1'])
   ....: 

In [49]: dfmi = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(len(miindex)*len(micolumns)).reshape((len(miindex),len(micolumns))),
   ....:                     index=miindex,
   ....:                     columns=micolumns).sort_index().sort_index(axis=1)
   ....: 

In [50]: dfmi
Out[50]: 
lvl0           a         b     
lvl1         bar  foo  bah  foo
A0 B0 C0 D0    1    0    3    2
         D1    5    4    7    6
      C1 D0    9    8   11   10
         D1   13   12   15   14
      C2 D0   17   16   19   18
         D1   21   20   23   22
      C3 D0   25   24   27   26
...          ...  ...  ...  ...
A3 B1 C0 D1  229  228  231  230
      C1 D0  233  232  235  234
         D1  237  236  239  238
      C2 D0  241  240  243  242
         D1  245  244  247  246
      C3 D0  249  248  251  250
         D1  253  252  255  254
```

And this is how they select the different rows:

```
In [51]: dfmi.loc[(slice('A1','A3'),slice(None), ['C1','C3']),:]
Out[51]: 
lvl0           a         b     
lvl1         bar  foo  bah  foo
A1 B0 C1 D0   73   72   75   74
         D1   77   76   79   78
      C3 D0   89   88   91   90
         D1   93   92   95   94
   B1 C1 D0  105  104  107  106
         D1  109  108  111  110
      C3 D0  121  120  123  122
...          ...  ...  ...  ...
A3 B0 C1 D1  205  204  207  206
      C3 D0  217  216  219  218
         D1  221  220  223  222
   B1 C1 D0  233  232  235  234
         D1  237  236  239  238
      C3 D0  249  248  251  250
         D1  253  252  255  254
```

So quite simply, in `df.loc[(indices),:]`, you specify the indices that you want to select per level, from highest level to lowest. If you do not want to make a selection of the lowest level(s) of indices, you can omit specifying them. If you don't want to make a slice between other specified levels, you add `slice(None)`. Both cases are shown in the example, where level D is omitted and level B is specified between A and C.

Comment: thanks for adding the updated solution. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you can use [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

**1. `group1 == 'a'`**

```
In [11]: df.query('group1 == "a"')
Out[11]: 
               value1  value2
group1 group2                
a      c          1.1     7.1
       c          2.0     8.0
       d          3.0     9.0
```

**2. `group1 == 'a' & group2 == 'c'`**

```
In [12]: df.query('group1 == "a" & group2 == "c"')
Out[12]: 
               value1  value2
group1 group2                
a      c          1.1     7.1
       c          2.0     8.0
```

**3. `group2 == 'c'`**

```
In [13]: df.query('group2 == "c"')
Out[13]: 
               value1  value2
group1 group2                
a      c          1.1     7.1
       c          2.0     8.0
```

**4. `group1 in ['a','b','c']`**

```
In [14]: df.query('group1 in  ["a", "b", "c"]')
Out[14]: 
               value1  value2
group1 group2                
a      c          1.1     7.1
       c          2.0     8.0
       d          3.0     9.0
b      d          4.0    10.0
       d          5.0    11.0
       e          6.0    12.0
```