# How do I really use the `ix` method of a pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Note: since I asked this question, `.ix` still exists but more or less has been replaced by `.loc` for label-based indexing and `.iloc` for positional indexing.

---

[Having read the docs one the `ix` method of DataFrames](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index), I'm a bit confused by the following behavior with my MultiIndexed DataFrame (specifying select columns of the index).

```
In [57]: metals
Out[57]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 24245 entries, (u'BI', u'Arsenic, Dissolved', -2083768576.0, 1.0) 
                        to (u'WC', u'Zinc, Total',         1661183104.0, 114.0)
Data columns:
Inflow_val      20648  non-null values
Outflow_val     20590  non-null values
Inflow_qual     20648  non-null values
Outflow_qual    20590  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2), object(2)

In [58]: metals.ix['BI'].shape  # first column in the index, ok
Out[58]: (3368, 4)

In [59]: metals.ix['BI', :, :, :].shape  # first + other columns, ok
Out[59]: (3368, 4)

In [60]: metals.ix['BI', 'Arsenic, Dissolved'].shape # first two cols
Out[60]: (225, 4)

In [61]: metals.ix['BI', 'Arsenic, Dissolved', :, :].shape # first two + all others
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-62-1fb577ec32fa> in <module>()
----> 1 metals.ix['BI', 'Arsenic, Dissolved', :, :].shape                              
# traceback spaghetti snipped
KeyError: 'no item named Arsenic, Dissolved'

In [62]: metals.ix['BI', 'Arsenic, Dissolved', :, 1.0].shape # also fails
```

It took me a long time to realize that what I had been trying to achieve with `In [61]` was possible with `In [60]`. Why does the `ix` method behave like this? What I'm really trying to get at is the scenario at `In [62]`.

My guess is that I need to redefine the index hierarchy, but I'm curious if there's an easier way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to select rows/columns based on MultiIndex level values i suggest using the ['.xs()'](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.xs.html?highlight=xs#pandas.DataFrame.xs) method. See also [Selecting rows from a Pandas dataframe with a compound (hierarchical) index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941492/selecting-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-with-a-compound-hierarchical-index)

For this example, you could use:

```
#short hand:
metals.xs('BI', level=0).xs('Arsenic, Dissolved', level=0).xs(1, level=1)

# more verbose
metals.xs('BI', level='bmp_category').xs('Arsenic, Dissolved', level='parameter').xs(1, level='storm')

# two chained `ix` calls:
metals.ix['BI', 'Arsenic, Dissolved'].ix[:, 1]
```