# In Python's Pandas, how do I filter a DataFrame on a Field in a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, filter, multi-index

I have this DataFrame that has a MultiIndex with the fiels **Hi**, **Md**, **Lo**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["A", "X", "C", "7", "3"],
        ["A", "B", "C", "7", "2"],
        ["A", "B", "C", "7", "1"],
        ["A", "X", "C", "7", "3"],
        ["1", "2", "3", "7", "3"],
        ["4", "5", "6", "7", "3"],
    ],
    columns=["Hi", "Md", "Lo", "O", "I"],
).set_index(["Hi", "Md", "Lo"])
```

It looks like this

```
          O  I
Hi Md Lo      
A  X  C   7  3
   B  C   7  2
      C   7  1
   X  C   7  3
1  2  3   7  3
4  5  6   7  3
```

How can I set a filter to get only rows where the **Md** has the value **B**

I tried via field name

```
df[df['Md'] == 'B']
```

This raises a KeyError, because the "field" is not column, but part of the MultiIndex

```
df[df.index.map(lambda x: x[1] == 'B')]
```

works, but is very hacky.

Is there a shorter way to write this filter, maybe using the field name **Md** or the index position **1**?

Comment: `df.xs('B', level='Md', axis='index')` (xs = "cross section")

Comment: This question (mine) from _years_ ago, is a bit outdated, but the answer still applies https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12047418/how-do-i-really-use-the-ix-method-of-a-pandas-dataframe

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DataFrame.query`

```
df.query("Md == 'B'")
```

Output

```
          O  I
Hi Md Lo      
A  B  C   7  2
      C   7  1
```

Alternative (Might not work with different data)

```
df.filter(like='B', axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way by passing a tuple in to `df.loc`

```
df.loc[(slice(None),'B',slice(None))]
```