# create multiple index for a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe dat1:

```py
Asset   Returns
DJ  0.1
SP  0.2
USDJPY  0.03
USDMXN  1.2
```

I have another dataframe dat2:

```py
Country Class   Asset
USA E   DJ
USA E   SP
USA FX  USDJPY
USA FX  USDMXN
```

How do I use dat2 to create an index for dat1; dat1 and dat2 have a common
column "Asset"

```
>new_dat=dat_corr.merge(dat_class,on="Asset",how="right").set_index(['Country','‌​Class','Asset'])
>new_dat.shape
(89, 89) 
>temp1='UNITEDSTATES' 
>temp2='Equity'
>new_dat.loc[ (new_dat.index.get_level_values('Country').isin([temp1]) &   new_dat.index.get_level_values('Class').isin([temp2]))]'
```

This gives me [3 rows x 89 columns]. My 89 columns is a mix of Equity/FX/FI/Commodities. If I want only USA Equities vs all other equity and not the entire 89 columns how do I do it? So I thought if I can create an index for the columns as well and use a similar approach?

Comment: Sorry are you asking to merge the 2 dfs on `Asset` column? Can you show desired output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this is what you are looking for:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['DJ', 0.1],
    ['SP', 0.2],
    ['USDJPY', 0.03]]),
    columns=['Asset', 'Returns'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.array([
    ['USA', 'E', 'DJ'],
    ['USA', 'E', 'SP'],
    ['USA', 'FX', 'USDJPY']]),
    columns=['Country', 'Class', 'Asset'])

df1.merge(df2, on="Asset")
```

Which produces an output of

```
   Asset Returns Country Class
0      DJ     0.1     USA     E
1      SP     0.2     USA     E
2  USDJPY    0.03     USA    FX
```

Since your wording is not completely clear if you wish to maintain an integer index or if you wish to use `Asset` as your main index and per the suggestion of @JBradley you can do:

```
df1.merge(df2, on="Asset").set_index(['Country','Class','Asset'])
```

which will give you a final data frame that looks like:

```
   Asset Returns Country Class
      DJ     0.1     USA     E
      SP     0.2     USA     E
  USDJPY    0.03     USA    FX
```

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on="Asset").set_index(['Country','Class','Asset'])`                 if you want dat2 as the index

Comment: @JBradley Very true. The OP's wording is a bit ambiguous as they state they wish to make `Asset` "AN index" rather than a more explicit wording like "THE index". I'll add your comment as an edit.

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. That is exactly what i wanted (dat2 as the index). being a newbie i dont understand why you had to use np.array when it seems to work directly with two pd.dataframes

Comment: Just a followup question: Is it possible to select only USA and E using df1.ix['USA','E']?

Comment: I found the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20754746/using-boolean-indexing-for-row-and-column-multiindex-in-pandas but this led to another question. Is it possible to have index for both rows and columns?

Comment: @user2819398 What do you mean by having an index on both? And I didn't need to use `np.arrays`, the code I happened to copy and edit for that bit was implemented with `np.arrays`.

Comment: "new_dat=dat_corr.merge(dat_class,on="Asset",how="right").set_index(['Country','Class','Asset'])
 new_dat.shape
(89, 89) temp1='UNITEDSTATES'
temp2='Equity'
new_dat.loc[
    (new_dat.index.get_level_values('Country').isin([temp1])
     & new_dat.index.get_level_values('Class').isin([temp2]))]. This gives me [3 rows x 89 columns]. My 89 columns is a mix of Equity/FX/FI/Commodities. If i want only USA Equities vs all other equity and not the enitre 89 columns how do i do it? So i thought if i can create an index for the columns as well and use a similar approach?

Comment: @user2819398 you should add that code to the original question with an "edit" and with some context of what it is you're trying to do because it's almost impossible to read in unformatted comment.

Comment: @user2819398 I suggest making a new question regarding the edit that you made. You would have a much higher chance of receiving an answer.