# Python, showing a specific data row on a graph

Tags: python, matplotlib

So, I've made a graph that plots multiple rows from a .csv file onto one graph. I want to make another graph that only includes specific rows to better analyze them.

My data is (only a portion of the total):

```
Number  Base-BW  1-BW    2-BW   3-BW    4-End-BW
182-14  39.7    41.1    40.3    39.5    38.8
95-14   43.3    41      41.9    42.4    41.6
15-14   59.4    59.4    59.1    59.1    56.4
124-14  76.4    77.4    74.8    74.5    68.1
183-14  35      35.5    36.8    37.3    35.4
```

My current script is:

```
# import all needed modules
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
# Set some Pandas options
import matplotlib.colors as cl
cl.Colormap('hsv')
plt.plot([0,1,2,3,4], (df['Base-BW'],df['1-BW'],df['2-BW'],df['3-BW'],df['4-End-BW']))
plt.axis([0, 4, 0, 100])
plt.xlabel('Day')
plt.ylabel('Weight (g)')
plt.title('Body Weight')
plt.legend(df['Number'], bbox_to_anchor=(1.1, 1.01))
plt.show()
```

Which yields:

[image]

So is there a way to just show, say, row1 (182-14), 3 (15-14), and 5 (183-14)? Or maybe just to graph those specific rows? I've checked other questions, and none pertain to using a .csv file like I am.

Comment: might help, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13428318/reading-rows-from-a-csv-file-in-python)

Comment: You're not showing entirety of your code, what is `SelectBreed` how exactly do you read in your data? (I don't see a function or a csv reader that does that for you). Generally there is no universal function that does that. Your best bet is to read in csv file and store each line in a list, i.e. `line`, as a list and then plot it like `plt.plot(x_values, line[i]` where x values seem to be days (although your code plots a `[1,2,3,4]` as days. I might be missing something, but it doesn't look like that code should produce your result. Then again it depends a lot on what `SelectBreed` is.

Comment: I updated it to include the entire code, I didn't know if that was necessary or not. Still kinda new to python.

Comment: If you want us to test *your* data, making it as easy as possible to reconstitute it on our machines will help -- usually you can write out a section of the data structure as a string that can be re-read without, e.g., saving a file to disk. Which is a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pandas library rocks for reading .csv files and then analyzing them. Using a sample dataset from R,

```
import pandas as pd
cw = pd.read_csv('ChickWeight.csv')
cw.columns
```

> Out[166]: Index([u'weight', u'Time', u'Chick', u'Diet'], dtype='object')

```
cw[cw.Chick==1].plot('Time','weight')
```

[image]

Picking apart that last line: `cw[cw.Chick==1]` is all rows of `cw` for which Chick==1; pandas dataframes have a plot method (which is matplotlib, I think, so will be familiar).

You can also do complicated selections from the dataframe, there are some good related pandas questions.

edited to add: [use a list of values to select rows from a pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12096252/use-a-list-of-values-to-select-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe?rq=1) is probably the most literal approach to your question; [Selecting rows from a Pandas dataframe with a compound (hierarchical) index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11941492/selecting-rows-from-a-pandas-dataframe-with-a-compound-hierarchical-index?rq=1) is pretty cool for doing selections based on more than one column (comes up all the time in multi-factor experiments).

Comment: The out for the cw.columns didn't show, is there a way you can edit it? Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, I'll check all of those out!

Comment: ... The result in this answer, or when you ran a similar script?